# Style the default caption menu in the video tag with css

Tags: html, css, web, html5-video

In a mobile view, the video element is resized according to the video aspect ratio. But the captions settings box is too large and some options cannot be seen.

Is there a way to lower that box or change it's height with css?

[Pic that demonstrating the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2PH.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by adding this to your code :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .intendedObject {
        height: 128px; //Desired value instead of 128px
     }
}
```

In `(max-width: 600px)` part, `600px` is the maximum size of screen you want. If it be less `600px`, the style written will be applied.